# bootstrap4C change function with a delay no function?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, this, prop

I'm using Bootstrap4C UI, and I want to cancel the **checked** property of a particular element after some delay time. You can see the options I have tried on next example:

```
 $('.button_onoff').change(function()
 {
    console.log("pay_onoff change");

    /*(1). This works! */
    $(this).prop('checked',false);

    /*(2). This fails! */
    setTimeout(function(this) {
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
    }, 5000);

    /*(3). This fails! */
    $.wait(5000).$(this).prop('checked',false);

    /*(4). This fails! */
    $.wait(5000);
    $(this).prop('checked',false);

    /*(5). This fails! */
    $(this).delay(5000).prop('checked',false);

});
```

How can I use the **this** and **delay** function to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Can you provide the html markup for the element with class **button_onoff**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
          var self = $(this);
          setTimeout(function() {
            self.prop('checked',false);
          }, 5000);
```